# typeof(1) prints "Number" to the console, but when i ask if typeof(1) == Number, it prints out false, why?

Tags: javascript, boolean, typeof

typeof(1) prints "Number" to the console, but when i ask if typeof(1) == Number, it prints out false, why ?

```js
console.log(typeof(1));
//Number

console.log(typeof(1) == Number);
//false
```

Comment: Note typeof is an *operator*, not a function; the parentheses aren't needed: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: `typeof` is an operator not a function. it works without parenteses.

Comment: `typeof 1` produces *the string* `"number"`

Comment: @AfnanBinHaque please check my answer and mark as correct if it helped you, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

`typeof` returns a string , so check against one

```js
typeof(1) == 'number' // true

// or better without ( ), since you don't need them here
typeof 1 == 'number' // true
```

and it should be fine.
More background info on `typeof` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

Comment: `typeof` is an operator not a function. it works without parenteses.

Comment: While this is true @NinaScholz, it works with parenteses as well, and OP choose to use them.

Comment: yes op use it, but it is superfluous to use it in this context. every value can be wrapped in parentheses, but if has no functional use, it should be avoided, not only it makes code longer, but also it points to a missing part or leftover.